# Java lazy initialization for nonstatic methods?

Tags: java, lazy-loading

I recently fell in love with the lazy-loading technique that is used as follows:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  static class ComplexClassHolder
  {
   static ComplexClass complex = new ComplexClass(); // takes a long time
  }

 static double someMethod(int x, int y)
 {
  return ComplexClassHolder.complex.calculate(x,y);
 }

 public double quickMethod() // if only this method is called there is no initialization of the instance of ComplexClass
 {
  return 1.0+1.0;
 }
}
```

But is a similar technique also possible for nonstatic methods?

**Example**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SomeClass
{
    final int seed;

    public SomeClass(int seed)
    {
        this.seed=seed;
    }

    class ComplexClassHolder
    {
        Random r = new Random(SomeClass.this.seed); // let's pretend this takes a long time
    }

    public double randomDouble()
    {
        return ComplexClassHolder.r.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the above is not possible, because ComplexClassHolder and ComplexClassHolder.r are not static. If I make them static however, I don't have access to SomeClass.this.seed.

I know I can do it with getInstance() and synchronization but if would really appreciate if the elegant technique possible in the static case could somehow be used here as well.

Answer (score 4):

What you see as "elegant" looks confusing and silly to experienced programmers.

When you look at the following example you see that there are no implicit side effects caused by the language or class loader specification. Everything it does is right there in the code you see. You also understand that trickery is not beautiful.

```
public synchronized double getNextDouble() {
    if (r == null) {
        r = new Random();
    }
    return r.nextDouble();
}
```

You might also realize that if you fall in love with a hammer, all your problems start to look like nails. :)

Comment: I might add that lazy loading is used way more often than it is actually needed. Programmers want to use it because it is a neat trick. Quite often it is implemented before any performance analysis is made.

Comment: That's very true, but when there is a huge performance drag (initializing MxN matrices) it is a performance must. In an environment where all objects that are used in the lifespan of the application are initialized at the beginning, it's really important. (Object pools)

Comment: Torben, you are calling Joshua Bloch silly then. The idiom is from Effective Java, "lazy initialization holder class idiom".

Comment: The performance is my case is noticiable (several seconds for the initialization) as the frequent delays brought me to the idea to use lazy loading there in the first place. The real problem is unfortunately more complex than in the example code because there are several methods that use the instance ("r" here) and I don't want to block all of them until one of them finished using it.

Comment: Marko, it works and I don't deny it. I look at it from the viewpoint of a professional Java programmer who has to work with people who are "less-than-Joshua-Blochs." Simplicity and understandability is my number one concern. The idiom requires more understanding that most programmers have and that makes it bad.

Comment: Check Bloch's own comments on that here: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Interviews/bloch_effective_08_qa.html.  He also gives a suggestion on how to do it for instance fields.  He also clearly mentions to avoid it when it's not needed, and suggests the synchronized method when correctness is more important than performance.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx Well certainly, if you don't need top performance then you don't need exotic idioms. And Torben, if coding for the common denominator of developer is the primary concern, a top-notch optimized idiom is still not "silly".

Comment: Marko, can not deny that. But... :) in the hands of a fresh programmer, it may just become the right tool to all problems. And I would be pleased if that did not happen.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The main reason for doing this is to make sure you have but one instance, not to shave off a few milliseconds.  That's what he means by correctness.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx I think all three of us actually agree on all points :) My reaction was to a (to my eyes) misleading remark on the lazy-init class holder idiom since it is a very valid idiom, especially so for an experienced programmer (who knows why he uses it, when he uses it).

Comment: I thought about this thoroughly and I am now convinced that the idiom should not be used. Because it relies on implicit behavior, even experienced programmers have to stop and think about why it works. I didn't know about the idiom before reading this but I figured out why it works. It took me maybe 10 seconds. That may be a small amount of time, but that time breaks the "thought flow" when trying to figure out how something in the same piece of code works and that break causes more loss of time. The amount of processor time saved with this trick can never make up the time lost in maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

The technique you describe relies on Java's lazy class loading (which is guaranteed by the spec) so it will only work for application-wide singletons. What you are trying to achieve is pass an instance variable into the lazy-inited object. If you still want it to be an application-wide singleton and initialized only once, you can still make it work by writing your seed to a static field that your static class will see.